# Maintaing page number of MVC 2 pagination on refresh

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, pagination

I'm using MVC 2 Pagination (not the jquery one) and my partial page gets refreshed in every 5 second.

I want to maintain my page number on refresh. Can you please suggest me how that can be done.

Here is the code for the page refresh in every 5 sec

```
setInterval(function () {
    $.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            url: '<%=Url.Action("divtobeupdated", "DefaultController") %>',
            data: {},
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (result) { $("#FileListContainer").html(result); }
        }
    )
    }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try 2 solution:

1) you pass the number of the page to the server and you pass it back to the view(no so good because you hace to change many code)
2) set a javascript global variable  and you set it in the setInterval, like this:

```
var numOfPage;
setInterval(function () {
numOfPage = getNumofPage();
$.ajax(
    {
        type: "GET",
        url: '<%=Url.Action("divtobeupdated", "DefaultController") %>',
        data: {},
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (result) {
                       //heare you can use numOfPage
                       $("#FileListContainer").html(result);

                       }
    }
)
}, 5000);
```

I hope understund good your question.

Marco

Comment: thnx
m trying sumthing like that only

Comment: let's me know if it worked for you, if not share with us more code for find a better solution